# Creating a list in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, structure

I am currently learning about pointers and structures, and I am working on an exercise.
My goal is to write a function head_insert which basically creates a new list element and it appends it to the front.

Note: I know that there's already a datatype list in c++, however this is just for exercising and understanding the concept behind dynamic structures better.

My code is the following:

```
struct list{
    int val;
    list *next = NULL;
};

typedef list* ptr_list;

ptr_list head_insert(ptr_list head, const int element){
    ptr_list tmp_head;
    tmp_head = new list;
    tmp_head->val = element;
    tmp_head->next = head;
    return tmp_head;
}

int main(){
    ptr_list head = NULL;
    head = head_insert(head, 1); // This is the crucial step I think, as head is not initialized yet
    head = head_insert(head, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is, I want the function head_insert also to work when head is NULL, i.e. my list is empty. However, when debugging my code, I notice that after each call of head_insert head stays NULL, however changes within head(head->val, head->next) are made.

Why is that? Has that something to do with the scope of tmp_head?
How could i modify my code to work in the way I intended?

If I dont set head to NULL in the beginning, but allocate space and setting it manually to the first element, everything works perfectly fine:

```
head = new list;
head->val = 1;
```

Thanks for your time and help!
Cheers

Comment: I don't see the issue.  `head` seems to be changing: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baf503d3389a8cac

Comment: The code looks normal . Maybe you have some problem with debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK and `head`definitely changes after `head_insert` is called.

However, saying

> changes within head(head->val, head->next) are made

is wrong, you don't "change" head from `head_insert`, you create a new object `tmp_head` and later it's assigned to `head` when `head_insert` returns.

When you were using your debugger, you probably noticed that `head` remains `NULL` within `head_insert` execution, which is absolutely normal. Later, when the function returns, `tmp_head` is copied to `head` (as you did `head = head_insert(head, 1);`) and only then `head` is changed from `NULL` to something not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is weird. The Eclipse Debugger shows that head = 0x0 the entire time. However, you're right, when I print out head after every single call of head_insert, I can see that its value is actually changing.

I solved the original problem which lead me to debugging my code. It was setting the pointer to NULL in the beginning. I didn't do that in the beginning and then the program terminated after the inserts/failed to work on the list(printing it out).